# EntryPointNotFoundException loading a C DLL in VB.net

Tags: c, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I've spent hours trying to get this simple test case working, and searching the internet for clues.

I have a VS 10 solution containing my VB.net project, and a VC++ DLL project.

In my DLL project i have:

json_main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C"
{
    void testMethod(int* inVal )
    {
        *inVal += 5;
    }
}
```

JSON.def:

```
LIBRARY JSON
    DESCRIPTION 'Simple JSON encoder/decoder'
    EXPORTS
        testMethod
```

And my VB.net code:

```
<DllImport("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/facebook/AlumniFinder/Debug/JSON.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Private Shared Sub testMethod(ByRef inVal As Integer)

End Sub
...

Dim var As Integer = 7
testMethod(var)
oLabel.Text = var.ToString
```

Yet when I try to run, I get the `EntryPointNotFoundException`.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?  I tried using dumpbin.exe on my DLL, but I don't get any function names out of it to determine the mangling scheme it is using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dumpbin /exports` or Dependency Walker to check that you are exporting the function since it would seem that you are not.

My guess is that you didn't configure the build to pass the .def file to the linker. Do it like in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I Just built the project as a DLL, I read a tutorial that mentioned nothing of how the .def file was used, I assumed that VS would interpret the extension and use it accordingly

Comment: when i use `dumpbin /exports JSON.dll` I don't see anything indicating an export, which leads me to believe you're correct that I'm not, and I need to make sure the .def file is used, how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without the path, and with `External`):

```
<DllImport("JSON.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Private Shared External Sub testMethod(ByRef inVal As Integer)
```

And make sure the JSON.dll is in the output directory (where the program is run from).